# Is $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} zf(z) = 0$ sufficient to show $f(z)$ has a removable singularity or must we check $\lim f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

The function 
$$f(z) = \frac{\exp(\frac{z}{z-5})-1}{z(z+1)}$$

Has the singularities $-1$, $0$ and $5$.

The singularity at $-1$ is a pole of degree one as

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow -1}(z+1)f(z) = -e^{\frac{1}{6}}+1 \ne 0$$

Now the singularity at $0$ is removable. To find the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}zf(z) = 0$ is easy, whereas finding the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)$ is much harder, but necessary for Riemann's Theorem on removable singularities in the strict form I have seen.

To show the singularity at 0 is removable, is the first limit $zf(z)$ sufficient? I think it should be (principal part of the Laurent series is 0), but I haven't seen it formally stated anywhere.

Comment: Yes, the first limit is sufficient.

Comment: That is condition (4) in [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem)

Comment: See https://www.math.uci.edu/~brusso/220C040908.pdf theorem 2.1 which makes no mention on the limit for $f$ alone.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch There is a condition that is no being mentioned in the question and, at least one of the answers, (LOL in the one currently selected actually), which is that the singularity in question is isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is sufficient: $\lim_{z\to0}zf(z)=0$ if and only if $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$ (assuming that, as in this case, $f$ is analytic).

However, it is easy to compute $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$. Take $g(z)=\exp\left(\frac z{z-5}\right)$. Then $g'(0)=-\frac15$ and therefore$$\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac1{z+1}\times\frac{g(z)}z=g'(0)=-\frac15.$$

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check the limit of $f(z)$. The relevant theorem is:

> **Theorem (Riemann).** If $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ is open, $z_0 \in U$, and $f: U \setminus \{z_0\} \to \mathbb C$ is homolorphic, then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ admits a holomorphic extension to $U$;
> 2. $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$;
> 3. $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z) = 0$.